# My flutter web build doesn't work the same as in debug

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I made a website in flutter and then I got a build. But the version in web debug and build does not work the same.

Only the background gif appears on the page. It also appears transparent.

I ran the site in xampp and various hosts for testing purposes and I changed browser but still got the same error.

i rebuild that project.And i used "flutter doctor" , "flutter clean" but didnt work.

It doesn't appear that there is an error in the Web Console.

web debug result :

[image: web debug image]

----

build result

[image: build image]

*When I built this project for android, it worked fine and gave the same result.*

*I also built the classic code of fllutter for web and it produced the same result without any problems.*

-----------------edit1------------------------------------

i added appbar to my code and i saw it was added in build without any problem.
[image: appbar image]

-------------------------edit2----------------------------

then in my code I removed the stack widget attached to the body property of scaffold and I painted all the containers red.And I saw that the rows instead of the whole page are grayed out.(note: the background gif was in the stack, I removed it as well.)

[image]

-------------------------edit3----------------------------

I found another similar question in SO.

[a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68608970/when-i-build-the-web-using-flexiblespacebar-and-check-it-on-the-web-not-the-too)!

-------------------------edit3----------------------------

I noticed a important thing.

I found the problem but I don't understand why it happened and how to fix it.

If the expanded and fittedbox widgets in the stack are removed, the problem disappears.

page 1(problematic state) :

```
return Stack(
      children: [
        Positioned.fill(
          child: Container(
            child: Image.asset(
              "ImageAssets/mobile.gif",
              fit: BoxFit.fill,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Center(
          child: Positioned(
            top: 0,
            left: 0,
            child: Container(
              width: 1200,
              height: 3999,
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  Expanded(
                    flex: 1,
                    child: SingleChildScrollView(
                      controller: _scrollController,
                      child: Container(
                        width: 600,
                        height: 1000,
                        color: Colors.brown.withOpacity(0.2),
                        child: Column(
                          children: [
                            buttonFunc("Home",_scrollController,context),
                            buttonFunc("Home",_scrollController,context),
                            buttonFunc("Home",_scrollController,context),
                            buttonFunc("Home",_scrollController,context),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    flex: 3,
                    child: SingleChildScrollView(
                      child: Container(
                        height: 3999,

                        child: Column(
                          children: [

                            TextBox(leftMarginValue: widthSize/4,topMarginValue: heightSize/20,insideText: "Testibulum arcu elit, interdum vel porttitor eu.",context: context),
                            TextBox(leftMarginValue: widthSize/80,topMarginValue: heightSize/20,rightMarginValue: widthSize/4-widthSize/80,insideText: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.",context: context),

                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
```

page 2 (problematic state):

```
child: Stack(
          children: [
            Container(

              height: heightSize / 8,
              width: widthSize / 5,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadiusDirectional.circular(22),
                color: Colors.grey,
                border: Border.all(color: Colors.white, width: 2),
              ),
              child: Center(
                child: Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsetsDirectional.only(
                      start: widthSize / 80,
                      end: widthSize / 80,
                      top: heightSize / 80,
                      bottom: heightSize / 80),
                  child: Expanded(
                    child: FittedBox(
                      child: Text(
                        softWrap: false,
                        overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,

                        insideText,


                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: widthSize / 50, color: Colors.white),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
```

If I build the above codes, the screen is completely gray.

page 2 (expanded and fitted removed from Stack) :

```
return Stack(
      children: [
        Container(
          child: Image.asset(
            "ImageAssets/mobile.gif",
            fit: BoxFit.fill,
          ),
        ),
        Center(
          child: Container(
            width: 1200,
            height: 3999,
            child: Row(
              children: [
                SingleChildScrollView(
                  controller: _scrollController,
                  child: Container(
                    width: 600,
                    height: 1000,
                    color: Colors.brown.withOpacity(0.2),
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        buttonFunc("Home",_scrollController,context),
                        buttonFunc("Home",_scrollController,context),
                        buttonFunc("Home",_scrollController,context),
                        buttonFunc("Home",_scrollController,context),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                SingleChildScrollView(
                  child: Container(
                    height: 3999,

                    child: Column(
                      children: [

                        TextBox(leftMarginValue: widthSize/4,topMarginValue: heightSize/20,insideText: "Testibulum arcu elit, interdum vel porttitor eu.",context: context),
                        TextBox(leftMarginValue: widthSize/80,topMarginValue: heightSize/20,rightMarginValue: widthSize/4-widthSize/80,insideText: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.",context: context),

                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
```

page 2 (expanded and fitted removed from Stack):

```
child: Stack(
          children: [
            Container(

              height: heightSize / 8,
              width: widthSize / 5,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadiusDirectional.circular(22),
                color: Colors.grey,
                border: Border.all(color: Colors.white, width: 2),
              ),
              child: Center(
                child: Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsetsDirectional.only(
                      start: widthSize / 80,
                      end: widthSize / 80,
                      top: heightSize / 80,
                      bottom: heightSize / 80),
                  child: Text(
                    softWrap: false,
                    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,

                    insideText,


                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: widthSize / 50, color: Colors.white),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
```

If I build the above codes, the gray goes away.

here is the build example of the new codes

[image: build example of new code image]

Comment: Can you try canvas rendering.

Comment: i did but nothing changed

Comment: Do this first:
[Web Cache](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61287128/15285043). 
Then clear your browser's cache.
`flutter build web --web-renderer canvaskit --relese`. 
Then can you build like this and check again? Will it work?

Comment: yes i did  , but it didn't work

Comment: Did you try to inspect the network tab in the browser ?

Comment: Yes i did.Actually, I don't understand much about inspect to the network, but there is no error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I fixed the error.

The graying is because I used incorrect layout widgets in the stack structure.
Here is the most confusing part. When you get **debug**, these errors can be fixed, but when you get **build**, it causes graying.

There are 3 steps to remove the gray for this code.

before : [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4J13U.png)

1- In the code below, it is necessary to remove the `Positioned.fill` widget.

When you remove this widget you will remove the gray that covers the screen.

after : [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q185g.jpg)

```
return Stack(
      children: [
        Positioned.fill(  //you have to remove this widget to solve the problem
          child: Container(
            child: Image.asset(
              "ImageAssets/mobile.gif",
              fit: BoxFit.fill,
            ),
          ),
        ),
```

before : [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/prbTd.jpg)

2- To solve the problem that the sidebar is gray, the expanded that wraps the text needs to be removed

after : [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qYCgK.jpg)

```
child: Expanded(  //you have to remove this widget to solve the problem
                    child: FittedBox(
                      child: Text(
                        softWrap: false,
                        overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,

                        insideText,


                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: widthSize / 50, color: Colors.white),
                      ),
                    ),
```

before : [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uJaC1.jpg)

3- The expanded widget in AnimetedTextKit needs to be removed to solve the graying problem in the page's content.

after : [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CyEjf.jpg)

```
child: Expanded( //you have to remove this widget to solve the problem
        child: AnimatedTextKit(

          animatedTexts: [
            TypewriterAnimatedText(

              insideText,

              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              textStyle:  TextStyle(
                //was 20
                fontSize: widthSize/150+heightSize/150,
                color: Colors.white,
                height: heightSize/500 ,
              ),
              speed: const Duration(milliseconds: 200),
            ),
          ],
          totalRepeatCount: 4,
          pause: const Duration(milliseconds: 99000),
          displayFullTextOnTap: true,
          stopPauseOnTap: true,
        ),
      ),
```